# How to unjumble the texts on visualization in P5 processing?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

[Here is my visulization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTBeM.png), as you can see some of the text is overlapping, so does anyone have any clues on how to have a bit of spacing only for those 3 texts which are clustered?

[Here is my code](https://github.com/pranavjain96/Data-Visualization-P5.js/blob/master/pie.js)

I was thinking of a spacing like the one they have done [in this chart](http://bl.ocks.org/kgryte/5926740)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to figure out what cases cause that problem and after some debugging, I noticed that it happens when your `value` has a small number ( when it's smaller than around 8-12). Since you seem like having just 12 months in your chart, this number won't change and you can manually check for it, then give it a minimum number of 10-15 for example, depending on the distance you want.

I tried modifying your code to give variable `value` a minimum value of 10 when its smaller than that, it seems like working. I also added a line from the new point to the old one which you can remove if you don't like.

Code:

```
////This portion is used to display the month on the pie chart////////////////
    value=MaxValue(disease,wounds,other);

      value2=-1;
      var x2,y2;
      if(value<10)
      {
      value2=value;
      value=10; 

      x2=1500+1500/5+value2*10*cos(startAngle+(radians(15)));
      y2=1500/2 -100+value2*10*sin(startAngle+(radians(15)));
      }

      print(chart.data[i].month+" has value : "+value);

    x=1500+1500/5+value*10*cos(startAngle+(radians(15)));
    y=1500/2 -100+value*10*sin(startAngle+(radians(15)));
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(5);
    point(x,y);
    if(value2!=-1)
    {
      point(x2,y2);
      strokeWeight(1);
      line(x,y,x2,y2);
    }
    strokeWeight(0);
    textSize(18);
    fill(0);
    text(chart.data[i].month,x+5,y+5);
```

Result:
[image]